# waiting for the domain for the long time while loading

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento website site and it is working fine, and almost ready now. Suddenly I'm facing a new problem, problem with this site is, its taking too much time to load. Actually not loading time this is, this is taking too much time to find the domain means waiting for `example.com` is appearing for a long time and then it get loaded. After entering URL in URL bar and pressing enter its loader icon is rotating in anti-clock wise for a long time and then start rotating in clock wise direction. I have tested this in all browser and this is happening with all browser.

Except home page every other pages is responding nicely while loading. this is only happening with the home page.

Comment: if this is happening for the home page only,check all phtml files which are rendering on home page.You might have used some loop conditions or trying to load some large collection on home page.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your DNS server. Try using a Google public DNS server as a test: `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: will you please explain about DNS server, how can i use this to test

Answer (score 1):

If your home page consists of lot of images.

```
1)Check the image files size.Try to keep image files size minimum.
2)Use png image instead of large size jpeg images
3)You can also try to compress the css files.
4)Try disabling log.
System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled: No 
5) Try re-indexing.
```

You need to set your cache method to apc after installing apc for php.

To do it, open file MAGENTO_DIRECTORY/app/etc/local.xml

Add following tags in

```
<cache>
<backend>apc</backend>
<prefix>YOURPREFIX_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Also confirm that all cache types are enabled in Magento admin System > Cache Management.

After editing local.xml, refresh all cache types.

You can check more information about your page load at http://gtmetrix.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's developer site to check it.
http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: there is some backend error for desktop and for mobile its fine..what it means ?

Comment: can you provide a URL?